# When trying to deploy the SSRS report getting error

Tags: ssrs-2008

Could not connect to the report server http://localhost/ReportServer. Verify that the TargetServerURL is valid and that you have the correct permissions to connect to the report server. (Microsoft Report Designer)

Answer (score 0):

Check you address than and check your SQL Server Report Configuration and please make sure that you are opening your report in Internet Explorer as an administ